# config files for different development environments (Production, Dev, Testing)

Tags: python, meta-programming, configuration

I am following a [guide](https://www.toptal.com/flask/flask-production-recipes) that specifies how to manage different configurations (DB_URI, LOGGER_NAME, etc...) per development environments.

I create a `config` module that is structured like this

`\my_project\config\__init__.py`

```
import os
import sys
from . import settings

# create settings object corresponding to specified env
APP_ENV = os.environ.get('APP_ENV', 'Dev')
_current_config = vars(setting).get(f'{APP_ENV}Config')

# copy attributes to the module for convenience
for atr in [f for f in dir(_current_config) if '__' not in f]:
    # environment can override anything
    val = os.environ.get(atr, getattr(_current_config, atr))
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], atr, val)
```

`\my_project\config\settings.py`

```
class BaseConfig:
    DEBUG = True
    LOGGER_NAME = 'my_app'


class DevConfig(BaseConfig):
    # In actuality calling a function that fetches a secret 
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite://user.db'


class ProductionConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = False
    # In actuality calling a function that fetches a secret
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite://user.db'
```

calling the config

`application.py`

```
import config
config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
```

This approach is kind of a hit and miss for me.
on one hand it allows me to easily specify several environments (dev, stage, prod, dev) without having a complex `if else` logic in my `settings.py`.

On the other hand I dont like using `setattr` on `sys.modules[__name__]`, seems a bit wonky to me. what do you think ?

Answer (score -1):

Incase you are using Docker for deployment. The **required environment variable** can be configured as **Kuberenetes configuration** and it reads based on the deployment configuration environment.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. Not all questions should be answered here, see [How do I write a Good Answer?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: thanks for the help, but my question is about python configuration. As I dont use docker at the moment